# ERROR: Cannot set priority of resourcemanager process 89885 and ERROR: Cannot set priority of nodemanager process 89986

Tags: macos, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I want to download Hadoop through Homebrew on Mac. I completed until formatting the namenode as `hdfs namenode -format`. I also removed the password requirement, but when I start the cluster under the sbin directory as `./start-all.sh`, the SecondaryNameNode, NameNode and Jps are getting startedm, but my NodeManager and ResourceManager isn't. What could be the possible reasons and how to get rid of the error so that when I do localhost:9870, hadoop will be displayed on the browser and I should be able to see the files under Browse the file system?

[image: Error image]

Because of the above error, I'm getting the following when Hadoop is opened on the browser.

[image: Error image]

I tried reinstalling hadoop, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `start-all.sh`. Use `yarn` command directly to start ResourceManager and Nodemanager directly, then look for more specific errors in the outputs of those commands

Similarly, use `hdfs namenode` and `hdfs datanode` commands to start those

Refer [Hadoop Startup](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html#Hadoop_Startup), but after you review the other sections on configuring hadoop's xml files

Also, your WebHDFS error has nothing to do with YARN. Hadoop doesn't start WebHDFS server by default... You should prefer using `hadoop fs -ls` commands, rather than using the browser for filesystem actions